# Swift - insertSubview usage

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

```
@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageView1: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    imageView1.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
    imageView1.image = UIImage(named: "logo2")

    let imageView2: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    imageView2.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 200)
    imageView2.image = UIImage(named: "1")

    myView.insertSubview(imageView1, at: 2)
    myView.insertSubview(imageView2, at: 1)

}
```

Hi, when I switch the insertSubview index, the z position of both images are still the same. How do you use insertSubview correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by position?

Comment: I meant z position. One on top of another. @hardikparmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intially, `myView` has no subviews.
So when you use insertSubview for first subview(`imageView1`)(whatever index you supply), it gets added at position `0`.

Now if you want to insert second subview(`imageview2`) but also want `imageView1` to appear above `imageView2`, then you need to insert the second subview at index 0.

For example:

> myView.insertSubview(imageView1, at: 0)
>
> myView.insertSubview(imageView2, at: 0)

In this case `imageView1` appears above `imageView2`

However,

> myView.insertSubview(imageView1, at: 0)
>
> myView.insertSubview(imageView2, at: 1)

Here, `imageView2` appears above `imageView1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    self. myView.insertSubview(imageView2, belowSubview: imageView1)
```

Comment: I want to apply to an array of images so i would prefer insert with index.

Comment: Please add a screenshot, what you want to achieve.